# Enum introduced by using declaration

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to understand enum which defined with nested-name-specifiers. What the standard says is `N4296:7.2/4 [dcl.enum]`:

> If the enum-key is followed by a nested-name-specifier, the
>   enum-specifier shall refer to an enumeration that was previously
>   declared directly in the class or namespace to which the
>   nested-name-specifier refers (*i.e., neither inherited nor introduced*
>   *by a using-declaration*), and the enum-specifier shall appear in a
>   namespace enclosing the previous declaration.

Well, why does the following example work, then?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A 
{
    namespace B
    {
        enum E : int;
    }
}
namespace C
{
    using A::B::E;
}

enum C::E : int { x = 2 };

int main()
{ 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/017f7b1d72edcc37)**

In the `namescape C`, we declared `enum E` by using declaration, and then referred to it with the enum definition. The compiler might have thrown an error, but it didn't. What was wrong, where was misunderstanding?

Comment: Looks like you've found a compiler bug.

Comment: @T.C. So, in general the following code shouldn't work too http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4e682437a639a1b right?

Comment: @T.C. Couldn't you get an example with the inheritance?

Comment: In your second set of code, `E` isn't a *nested-name-specifier* so the paragraph you cited doesn't apply. The global scope definition actually defines `::E`, a distinct enum from `A::B::E`. Combining that with the *using-declaration* is disallowed by 3.3.1 [basic.scope.declarative]/p4. (You'd get an ambiguity error if you try to use `E` or try to assign `x` to a variable of type `A::B::E`, though the compiler should have diagnosed it without this.) As to inheritance, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cd6f3dd5127b35.  @nbro I'm fairly sure I know what I'm talking about, thank you very much.

Comment: @T.C. What, you removed my comment?

Comment: @Rinzler: He does not have the powers to do that. I don't know what your comment said, but perhaps it was rude and flagged into oblivion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit People say my comments are rude just because they have never done anything else rather than sitting in front of a screen all the holy days thinking they are so intelligent to be superior to others. +1 for your answer :D

Comment: @Rinzler: Presumably your flagged comment was something like that one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Am I insulting someone? Maybe programmers still live in a fairy tale to get offended so quickly.

Comment: @Rinzler: And again! Curious.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, for the reasons you give, this is a compiler bug.
Interestingly, both Clang 3.5.0 and GCC 4.9 accept the program.